# imageUri : path to local file

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am accessing google vision api using requests.post method in python (jupyter notebook)

in imageUri i can only specify weburl or bucket uri. I cannot specify local file name like "/Users/pi/test.jpg"

```
file_name = '/Users/mbp/Pictures/full moon.jpg'
data = {
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
    "source":{
      "imageUri": file_name
    }
  },
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"FACE_DETECTION",
      "maxResults":1
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}

r = requests.post(url=url,json=data)
x= json.loads(r.text)
print(x['responses'])
```

response i get is:

```
[{'error': {'code': 3, 'message': 'image-annotator::Malformed request.: Unsupported URI protocol specified: /Users/mbp/Pictures/full moon.jpg'}}]
```

please help

Comment: Try `file:///Users/mbp/Pictures/full moon.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
unfortunately, its not working


    {'error': {'code': 3,
   'message': 'image-annotator::Malformed request.: Unsupported URI protocol specified: file:///Users/mbp/Pictures/full moon.jpg'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local files you need to load the file content, encode it, and put the encoded image content under the `content` key.  For details, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request).  The information about base64 encoding is linked on that page as well.

Your code can be updated as follows:

```
import base64

file_name = '/Users/mbp/Pictures/full moon.jpg'
with open(file_name, 'r') as image:
    image_content = image.read()
    encoded_content = base64.b64encode(image_content)

data = {
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
      "content": encoded_content
    },
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"FACE_DETECTION",
      "maxResults":1
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}

r = requests.post(url=url,json=data)
x = json.loads(r.text)
print(x['responses'])
```

Alternatively you might consider using the client libraries; some information [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: you are awesome !!

Comment: had some issues with utf-8 encoging ... but could fix it !!

Thanks again

Comment: @maswadkar Do you mind sharing the utf-8 encoding issue you ran into?

Comment: Surely 


The error I got was 



    **TypeError: b'/9j/4S/+RXhpZg........=' is not JSON serializable**



change i made was 


    **encoded_content = base64.b64encode(image_content).decode('utf-8')**